# how to forward soap messages in web service endpoint and write requests in a local database?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

I am a newbie in web service developement. I have a new project where i need to forward requests i receive from my clients through a web service gateway (let's call it Cyceon)  to another web service endpoint (Omega). But, i also need to write requests and responses in Cyceon's local sql database for reporting reasons.
Request: Client A --ws--> Cyceon database (write Client request) --ws--> Omega
Response: Omega --ws--> Cyceon database (write Omega response) --ws--> Client A
I have made the Cyceon --ws--> Omega connection and a test_client from which a send requests straight to Omega...but i don't know how to make the Cyceon endpoint which will retrieve requests from external clients, write data in a database and forward request in Omega.

Any help will be grateful.

Thanks in advance,
Sotiris

Answer (score 0):

Not a detailed question so the answer is also general.

If we are talking about WCF IIS-hosted web services then you can create a web service hosted by Cyceon that will serve as a contact endpoint for clients and will include a method that is called by clients. This method's body must include a logic that will fill the DB with appropriate data and then will make an appropriate call to Omega WS that you say you have already created.